# React router changes URL but not the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Hello I have a seperate route and links file in my react project and when clicking a link it changes the URL but not the view and I cant figure out why.

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from "./router";
import RenderSite from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><RenderSite /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('site-wrapper'));
```

This is my links file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderNav = () => {
    return(
        <div className="header-links">
            <Link to="/" className="link">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about" className="link">About</Link>
            <Link to="/contact" className="link">Contact Us</Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HeaderNav;
```

And finally this out my router.js

```
import React from 'react'
import HomePage from './pages/home'
import AboutPage from './pages/about'
import ContactPage from './pages/contact'
import {
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
    </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

Just for clarity here is an example of one of the pages im trying to load:

```
import React from 'react'
import PageLayout from '../components/layout'

class AboutPage extends React.Component  {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <PageLayout />
        <p>About page</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default AboutPage
```

Comment: Try adding ```withRouter``` in Route like this ```component={withRouter(MyComponent)}```

Comment: Where are you rendering the `Routes` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see your `App.js` code. You have imported `Routes` in `index.js` but have not used it. You need to add `Routes` component in your `App` component.Something like below:

```js
function App(){
  return(
    <div>
      {Routes()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import `BrowserRouter` and Wrap routes in `BrowserRouter`

```
import React from 'react'
import HomePage from './pages/home'
import AboutPage from './pages/about'
import ContactPage from './pages/contact'
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
     <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
     </Switch>
    </Router> 
);

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it didnt work everything is wrapped in a browserrouter tag in my index.js

Comment: @user2983251 Here is my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-meadow-ttpw6

Comment: @user2983251 can you share your requirement screenshot